# How to show <div> when user does not scroll the page

Tags: javascript, scroll

This simple code, hides the div "**Navbar**" when user scrolls down the page and shows the div,
when user scrolls up.

How to change this code - so the div will be **NOT visible** ONLY when user scrolls the page?
And when the user stops to scroll the div will appear on the screen?

```
<script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
} 
</script>
```

Please, help!
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using setTimeout. It works this way: When the user scrolls, the navbar is hidden and a timeout starts which will make the navbar visible if user does not scroll in the next 100 miliseconds.

```
// We need this to manage setInterval
var isScrolling;
navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
   navbar.style.top = "-" + navbar.style.height;
   window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );

   isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
       navbar.style.top = "0";
   }, 100);

}, false);
```

Give it a try.

Comment: I just have tried the proposed by you code

Comment: It makes the div visible all the time without any relation to mouse scroll : (

Comment: I forgot to add the 'px' after -50 here => `document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50";`. I've edited the answer, try again now, it should work. Lemme optimize it a little

Comment: Thank you for marking my answer! By the way, you can extract the navbar in a variable to have a more efficient code and to replace that hardcoded `-50px` with the actual height of the navbar ;) Check the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Say, please Dorin - How I can manage that additionaly the navbar hides down when the user clicks somewhere on the page or on this navbar ? (besides the scroll, additionaly to it!)

Comment: Say, please Dorin - How I can manage that additionaly the navbar hides down when the user clicks somewhere on the page or on this navbar ? (besides the scroll, additionaly to it!)

Comment: You may add a flag, a bool variable `hideOnScroll` and check it's value inside scrolling event handler (`if hideOnScroll == true - hide the navbar when scrolling, otherwise - exit the function`). While `hideOnScroll` in set to false, you control the navbar, when true - the onscroll event handler does.

Comment: This do not work.. probably I mispell something :*)

<script>
var isScrolling;

var hideOnScroll=false;

navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{

if hideOnScroll == true{

   navbar.style.bottom = "-" + navbar.style.height;
   window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );
   isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
       navbar.style.bottom = "-536";
   }, 100);
}, 
},
 false);
</script>

Comment: A better approach will be to check if hideOnScroll == false, then return, otherwise continue. Like this: `var isScrolling;
var hideOnScroll = false;
navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (!hideOnScroll)
        return;
    navbar.style.bottom = "-" + navbar.style.height;
    window.clearTimeout(isScrolling);
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function () {
        navbar.style.bottom = "-536";
    }, 100);
}, false);`       If you use VS Code, paste it, select it and press CTRL + K  CTRL + F and it will be automatically arranged

Comment: This code does not work for some reason : * ) - does nothing, navbar stays always down

Comment: Maybe mispell somewhere?